# on mouseover:Hide original url and show other

Tags: jquery, html, css

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWgbV.png)

Here i attached image and want to show other path here instead of original url.

Comment: yo can take two div.put each url in one div.by default make one div hide.on hover of visible div you can show hidden div.and hide own.this way u can achieve this

Answer (score 2):

1. Link to the desired page in the `<a id="hijackmyclick" href="http://LinkToShow.com"></a>`
2. Hijack the click with something like `$('#hijackmyclick').onClick(function() {window.location.href = "http://itsatrap.com"; return false;})`

P.S. This sounds pretty shady

Comment: <div class="ads-div" >
   <a href="http://originalurl.com/" ><img src="http://images//images/ads1.png" style="height: 232px;"></a>
   </div>

Comment: Uh, yes, that's html? Did you have a comment or a question?

Comment: i can set add through admin side this is code for add div.  url set through here.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean or how to help further, sorry.

Comment: I said .... Adds on where that url showing on mouseover.....

that is set from the admin side of website DYNAMICALLY. in plain HTML code which e send .  URL set there at admin side. then how can i get that url part